# Using Django JSONField in model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating REST API's.

```
django==3.2.2
djangorestframework==3.12.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
```

I am new to Django, python.
I looking for a way to use the JSON field in the Django model.
My model looks like below -

```
class Question(BaseModel):
.... other code...
    attributes = models.JSONField()
```

Now I want the attributes to be a JSON, like below

```
{
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "95161b18-75a8-46bf-bb1f-6d1e16e3d60b",
    "isActive": false,
    "latitude": -25.191983,
    "longitude": -123.930584,
    "tags": [
      "esse",
      "sunt",
      "quis"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Contreras Weeks"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dawn Lott"
      }
    ]
}
```

Should I create a new model, but creating a new model will make it add to migrations which I do not want.

1. How to create a model for the above?
2. How can I use the default validation provided by Django ORM on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out - we can use pydantic or schema for django. They offers validations also. I preferred pydantic.

1. https://github.com/keleshev/schema
2. https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/

**EDIT**

Pydentic example

Schema

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    StrictBool,
    StrictInt,
    StrictStr,
)

class Foo(BaseModel):
count: int
size: float = None


class Bar(BaseModel):
    apple = 'x'
    banana = 'y'

class AttributesSchema(BaseModel):
    point: StrictInt
    value: StrictStr
    foo: Foo
    bars: List[Bar]
```

will return JSON like

```
{
    'point': 2,
    'value': 'Any string'
    'foo': {'count': 4, 'size': None},
    'bars': [
        {'apple': 'x1', 'banana': 'y'},
        {'apple': 'x2', 'banana': 'y'},
    ],
}
```

Validation -
Add this to your serializer

```
 schema = AttributesSchema
 try:
   errors = schema.validate(data['attributes'])
 except Exception as errors:
   raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
```

Refer pydantic documents, it has everything we need.
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/

Answer (score 3):

Django now natively supports [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield).

Comment: still need jsonschema validators